# Gmail API returns 403 error code and usage limits error

Tags: android, api, gmail

I'm trying to add the gmail API to my application, but i get this error:

```
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765): {
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765):   "code" : 403,
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765):   "errors" : [ {
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765):     "domain" : "usageLimits",
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765):     "message" : "Access Not Configured. The API (Gmail API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765):     "reason" : "accessNotConfigured",
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765):     "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com"
03-02 15:30:23.555: W/System.err(7765):   } ],
03-02 15:30:23.556: W/System.err(7765):   "message" : "Access Not Configured. The API (Gmail API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
03-02 15:30:23.556: W/System.err(7765): }
03-02 15:30:23.557: W/System.err(7765):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
```

this is my Gmail API class:

```
public class GmailAPI { 
    private Context context;
    private final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly";
    private final String APP_NAME = "Gmail API Quickstart";

    public GmailAPI(Context context,String token,String user) throws IOException {
        this.context = context;

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);

        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();

        ListThreadsResponse threadsResponse = service.users().threads().list("me").execute();
        List<Thread> threads = threadsResponse.getThreads();

        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            Log.d(">>> Threads","Thread ID: " + thread.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

And in the developer Console i've created a new client id with the package name and sha1 of my application, and i've enabled also the Gmail API,Google+ API,Contacts API.

Comment: After following the [Gmail API Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android), I'm getting the same error message.  Did you discover the root cause?